# Why is data not coming out same after joining tables?

Tags: r

[Limit before joining the table looked something like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LPrMg.png)

[After joining 3 data frame I'm getting this output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KNVBj.png)

Why is the limit column coming out like this?

code used for joining the data frames:-

```
df <- Cust_Acqusition %>% dplyr::inner_join(Repayment, by = ('Customer'= 'Customer')) %>%
                          dplyr::inner_join(Spend, by = ('Customer' = 'Customer'))
```

Comment: Please don't upload code or data as images for [these reasons](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557).  How do you expect the `Limit` column to look?  What did it look like before?  Even better, what *values* did it contain before the joins?  What *values* does it contain now?

Comment: Is it the scientific notation that's a problem for you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can disable scientific notation with:

```
options(scipen = 999)
```